# How to display a pyqtgraph.TextItem over all other items in a scene?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, z-order

I'm attempting to have an `InfiniteLine` label appear over all other items in a pyqtgraph scene. I am setting the `zValue` of the label to 1, and all others to 0. In spite of this, the label still appears underneath other items in the scene. Here is a minimal example where the label for the `InfiniteLine` appears under the `LinearRegionItem` despite having a higher `zValue`.

```
from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget, PlotItem, InfiniteLine, LinearRegionItem, mkQApp


# app
app = mkQApp()

# items
line = InfiniteLine(pos = 5, label = "position: {value}", movable = True)
region = LinearRegionItem(values = (6, 10), movable = True, pen = "red", brush = "red")

# plot
plot = PlotItem()
plot.setXRange(0, 20)
plot.addItem(line)
plot.addItem(region)

# widget
widget = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
widget.addItem(plot, 0, 0)
widget.show()

# set zvalues
line.setZValue(0)
region.setZValue(0)
line.label.setZValue(1)

# run
app.exec()
```

Comment: Placing `plot.addItem(line)` after `plot.addItem(region)` works as expected for me without any `setZValue` code. I'm not convinced that `setZValue` works at all.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I believe that setZValue doesn't work because the line label item is parented to the line, not the plot (like the line and region are). I've decided to just make my own TextItem parented to the plot that appears whenever a plot item is hovered.